# Почему в WPF не реализован NotifyIcon как в WinForms?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я не могу понять, почему в WPF нет нативной возможности добавления иконки в трей.

И ладно, если это вообще нельзя было сделать по соображения безопасности, но можно же! 
Например, используя NotifyIcon из WinForms или сторонние реализации, такие как [Hardcodet WPF NotifyIcon](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf).

Но почему WPF не может предложить сделать это без сторонних сборок?

---

На англоязычном [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54402099/why-in-wpf-doesnt-implemented-notifyicon-like-in-winforms) затоптали в грязь, не обьяснив толком причины..
Ладно, если так случилось, значит мой вопрос действительно тупой, но это ничего не меняет, для меня вопрос по прежнему остается открытым.
Пожалуйста, постарайтесь донести до меня, в чем заключается тупость моего вопроса, даже если вы хотите закидать меня гнилыми помидорами.

Comment: В комментах там правильно отметили, что tray icon - это компонент ОС, он не относится ни к WinForm, ни к WPF. Платформа WPF предназначена для создания GUI. Для создания иконок в трее не предназначена. Следовательно, берем стороннюю библиотеку и всё.

Comment: Конечно, тут можно спросить: а почему тогда NotifyIcon добавили в WinForms, ведь эта платформа тоже для создания GUI, а не для создания иконок в трее. Ну, будем считать это недочетом разработчиков. Правильнее было бы поместить в другое пространство имён, имхо.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш комментарий!

Comment: По поводу "MS just so lazy". В книге "Лучшие примеры разработки ПО" (легкое чтиво) есть глава "Сколько работников Microsoft нужно для того, чтобы сменить лампочку". Глава короткая, всего 3 страницы, рекомендую ознакомиться.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я хоть и не в MS работаю, но ощущаю эту боль каждый день